# Xcode Error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) in Flutter project

Tags: xcode, flutter

I'm trying to build ios app of the flutter project, using google maps in it. Successfully built the app and the map is loading perfectly but if I navigate to a different screen in the app and come back to the map screen it crashes with the error. The error shows up in main.m file in  Runner folder

```
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it ! Changing the flutter channel does the trick.